# Projecting a symetric matrix on a subspace of known kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, projection

Given a symmetric matrix ${\bf S} \in S_n(\mathbb{R})$ and linearly independent vectors ${\bf u}, {\bf v}, {\bf w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, how can one numerically compute the projection of $\bf S$ onto the following linear subspace?

$$E := \left\{ {\bf N} \in S_n(\mathbb{R}), \{ {\bf u}, {\bf v}, {\bf w} \} \subset \ker{{\bf N}} \right\}$$

Comment: $\{ {\bf u}, {\bf v}, {\bf w} \} \subset \ker{{\bf N}}$ can be replaced by matrix multiplication

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo So you mean $E = \{N \in S_n(\mathbb{R}), N . (uvw) = 0\}$? What does it imply for the projection?

Comment: I mean a projection procedure that is useable in numerical computation context. Something tractable. As opposed to something implicit like the definition I gave of E.

Comment: Have you tried minimizing the Frobenius norm of $\bf X- S$ subject to the obvious constraints?

Comment: I am not a specialist of numerical methods or linear algebra in any way so nothing is really obvious to me. I don't know what type of minimization under constraint would be adapted here. Also it is not obvious to me how to formulate the constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality you can assume that $u,v,w$ are orthonormal. If not, use Gram Schmidt. Then complete it with an orthonormal basis $f_4,\ldots,f_n.$
Write the orthogonal matrix $U$ which change the canonical orthonormal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ into $(u,v,w, f_4,\ldots,f_n)$ Write by blocks

$$U^TSU=\left[\begin{array}{cc}S_1&S_2\\S_2^T&S_3\end{array}\right]$$ where $S_1$  is a $3\times 3$ matrix. The projection of $U^TSU$ on $E$ is simply $P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&S_3\end{array}\right].$ The projection of $S$ on $E$ is $UPU^T.$

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this might exist, but I had no idea of where to look for. Can you point me to the steps to derive this?

Comment: Well, this is standard linear algebra. Suppose that $u,v,w=e_1,e_2,e_3$ , the beginning of the standard basis of $R^n$. Then $E$ is nothing but the space of symmetric  matrices $(s_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$ where $s_{ij}=0$ when $1\leq i,j\leq 3.$ As a consequence the projection of any symmetric matrix $S=(s_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$  on $E$ is obtained by replacing all  $s_{ij}$ when $1\leq i,j\leq 3$ by zero. The rest of the 'proof' is the change of basis since in general $u,v,w\neq e_1,e_2,e_3$

Comment: I may be missing something, but from this last example, shouldn't P be $P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&S_3\end{array}\right]$ then?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks and apologies. I have to correct my answer

Comment: No problem and thank you again, this is precisely the answer I came for!